# In python on Mac unix/linux system string method isdigit() doesn't work

Tags: python

"3".isdigit() returns false in python 3 on Mac.  But it returns true in Spyder console or on a PC.  What is going on?

Comment: Not in my Python 3 interpreter. I'm getting `True` and I'm on a Mac.

Comment: Plz specify the exact version on your python interpreter

Comment: `repr()` returns?

Comment: What locale are you using on each computer?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem.  I was redirecting an input text file into the input statement of Python.  The input text files were constructed on a PC so that each line ended with CR-LF (2 characters).  But the execution was on a docker ubuntu container where Python expected a newline (1 character).  Apparently input strips the appropriate number of characters off the end of the line depending on the operating system.  Thus, the CR-LF was striped down to one character, neither of which would pass the isdigit() test.  I remade the input file on a Mac and the problem went away.